# Retrieve data from database and display it dynamically in the rows of the table using textboxes

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, netbeans

I'm currently working on an Inventory Management project. I m working with JSP and MySQL on Netbeans Platform. In my project on querying I need to retrieve values from the database and display it in a  table. The rows to be displayed should be dynamic in my page. They should be displayed in any number. Suppose When I want to retrieve values based on a particular choice I select, I should be able to display all the data based on the choice and display it in the rows of the table. I am not able to display it in multiple rows of my table because I m using text boxes to display the values.
Here is the code snippet:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select name="choice_type">
            <option>select</option>
            <option value="part_type">part_type</option>
            <option value="category">category</option>
            <option value="names">names</option>
            </select>    
        </td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <th>VAL</th>
        <th>VAL DESC</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <input type="text" name="val"  id="val" size="15" /></td>
        <td> <input type="text" name="val_desc"  id="val_desc" size="15" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>   

<input type="submit" name="Query" value="Query" onClick="getData();"/>
```

The getData() function is as follows:

```
function getData(){ 
    xmlHttp=GetXmlHttpObject()
    var id=document.getElementById("choice_type").value;
    var url="choice_retrieval.jsp";//The code for this file is defined below 
    url=url+"?choice_type="+id;
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=stateChanged 
    xmlHttp.open("GET",url,true)
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function stateChanged(){ 
    if(xmlHttp.readyState==4 || xmlHttp.readyState=="complete"){ 
    var showdata = xmlHttp.responseText; 
    var strar = showdata.split(":");
    if(strar.length>1){
    var strname = strar[1];
    document.getElementById("val").value= strar[1];
    document.getElementById("val_desc").value= strar[2];
   }
}
```

The Code snippet for choice_retrieval.jsp is as follows:

```
<%
    String ch = request.getParameter("choice_type").toString();
    System.out.println(ch);
    String data ="";
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://", "", "");
        Statement st=con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from master_panel where choice_type='"+ch+"'");
        while(rs.next())
        {
            data = ":" + rs.getString("val") + ": " + rs.getString("val_desc");
        }
        out.println(data);
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
%>
```

Database table used here is master_panel(choice_type varchar,val varchar,val_desc varchar). I have not put any constraints as of now. Based on the choice_type value I need to retrieve the corresponding data(val and val_desc) from the database and display it in dynamic rows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that the data is being returned (your `stateChanged` method is being invoked) you need to dynamically create the table rows (and their contents, the text boxes) in your `stateChanged` method by modifying the DOM.

To modify the DOM to create the table structure the code should read something like this (assuming you've already removed the previously displayed rows):

```
var table = document.getElementById('tableId');
var data = xmlHttp.responseText.split(":");

for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i + 2) 
{
  var valueText = document.createElement('input');
  valueText.type = 'text';
  valueText.name = 'value' + i;
  valueText.value = data[i];

  var valueCell = document.createElement('td');
  valueCell.appendChild(valueText);

  var descriptionText = document.createElement('input');
  descriptionText.type = 'text';
  descriptionText.name = 'value' + i;
  descriptionText.value = data[i + 1];

  var descriptionCell = document.createElement('td');
  descriptionCell.appendChild(descriptionText);

  var tableRow = document.createElement('tr');
  tableRow.appendChild(valueCell);
  tableRow.appendChild(descriptionCell);

  table.tBodies[0].appendChild(tableRow);
}
```

Also, as @TrueDub said, putting SQL in JSPs is bad for a whole host of reasons.  What's worse is building SQL queries with string concatenation - it opens your system to SQL injection attacks, especially when the string being concatenated includes a string captured in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing quite a few things wrong there, especially having database code within a JSP, but to answer your specific question, you should write your resultset into a list and set this list into the request scope with a specific id. You can then iterate over it using the JSTL tag  and display the output using the {} notation.

Comment: Agreed on the number of things being done wrong, but it looks like @Neal is trying to perform an Ajax call (see the getData method) once the page has been loaded client-side, so JSTL isn't the way forward.

Comment: @TrueDub : To retrieve the data from the database at the server I am making an AJAX call to the server. If I am wrong please help me out. My aim is to display data into the rows(textboxes) of the table. I m new to JSP so if u can provide me with any sample tutorial relating this it would be of great help to me.

Comment: @Nick Holt : If u can provide me with a sample tutorial which demonstrates the above concept it would be of great help to me. Thanx

Comment: See the tutorial on the JSTL SQL tags - http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL7.html